# How to spread the accumulator in a reducer when's empty?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to build an object that takes the `age` as the key and the value of that key would be an array with names corresponding to that.

The Array:

```
const arr = [{
    name: "Rita",
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 25
  },
  {
    name: "Barbara",
    age: 23
  },
]
```

What I want as an outcome:

```
const obj = {
  23: ["Rita", "Barbara"],
  25: ["John"]
}
```

I've built something with `reduce` but is breaking saying `...(acc[curr.age] || {}), curr.name` is not iterable.

My suspicious is that it doesn't like having the initial as an empty object (`{}`). But I can't have an initial with keys because they should be dynamic.

This is my non-working solution:

```
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return {
    ...(acc || {}),
    [curr.age]: [...(acc[curr.age] || {}), curr.name]
  }
}, {})
```

Comment: `(acc[curr.age] || [])`. ... it is/must-be an array.

Comment: What is wrong with just updating `acc`? This code is unreadable and doing all this spread dance doesn't add any value. It's probably much slower because of all the spread and creating object in every iteration.  `if(acc[curr.age]) acc[curr.age].push(curr.name) else acc[curr.age] = [curr.name]; return acc;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on `...(acc[curr.age] || {})`. `acc[curr.age]` is supposed to be an array, isn't it? Take a look at the final result you expect.

```js
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return {
    ...(acc || {}),
    [curr.age]: [...(acc[curr.age] || []), curr.name]
  }
}, {})
```

Check it [online](https://tio.run/##bY4xC8IwEEZ3f8Xh1EDMUBGkUAdHBwUdS4czTWuKJnJNC6L97ZrUggi96fh4PF6NHTaS9N0tuvVbWtM4QCJIIXvOwJ/Bm0pgftQO53xYsPJDvPR/H4Y/bGcv5g9bTWJbpDPSpDAfI@y59hE@RZAqWqmiCKXkIFsiBulm8JFyLZlRLYQICLxe8OzZ15wFXHh/nkA2Ar8toFnOvlIR0vLQMOt5MAwd9qrE1VbR7nTYi8aRNpUuH5GP49CaQpXaqIJDzNj7Aw).